# How it update the price when selected other element in the dropdown?

Tags: javascript, magento, magento-1.7, product, dropdown

I am trying change the price when I selected the other element but it didn't work.

I searched in file : configurable.js, but only see the function :reloadPrice and realoadOldPrice , I'd need your help please.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xgjb.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ojS0.jpg)

and file in magento  : /js/varien/configurables.js

```
  getOptionLabel: function(option, price){
 ........
   var sel = document.getElementById('attribute'+IdProduct);
  if(sel!=""){

      var opt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
      var text= opt.text;
      var text_array= text.split(" ");
      var PriceExcl=text_array[2];
      var cutpriceincl=text_array[3];
      if (cutpriceincl!=undefined) {
          PriceIncl=cutpriceincl.substring(1);


      }

  }
..........
},
```

I am trying change the price with javascript.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: A live demo will be useful

Comment: https://inoxtaps.com/cocoon-mono-set03-wall-mounted-cold-water-tap-3133 

this is the page and the product

Comment: are you able  to change the price of Excluding tax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code for updating the price.

```
var sel = document.getElementById('attribute'+IdProduct);
if(sel!=""){

  var opt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
  var text= opt.text;
  var text_array= text.split(" ");
  var PriceExcl=text_array[2];
  document.getElementById("price-excluding-tax-3133_clone").innerHTML = PriceExcl;
  var cutpriceincl=text_array[3];
  if (cutpriceincl!=undefined) {
      PriceIncl=cutpriceincl.substring(1);
       document.getElementById("price-including-tax-3133_clone").innerHTML = PriceIncl;

  }

 }
```